# Flask send weekly automated emails

Tags: python, flask, cron

I want to be able to send automated weekly emails to users that have an account to my app. For example, every Monday send last week's summary of what they did in the app (how many posts they published, comments etc). I have my flask API all working, I can send async emails with celery everything works. How can I add the automated weekly emails? Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Option 1: Use a cron job to run the method which sends the report. 
Option 2: Create a service to do the same.
Option 3: Run a separate worker which will send email weekly at a specific time.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]